# Tool to quality check uploaded documents (mainly PDFs): Identify blur (maybe by trying OCR), edges

Tags: pdf, quality-assurance

For our loan application we need our borrower applicants to upload a lot of documents.

Therefore, it would be great to have a tool that automatically gives out an error for the bad quality of an uploaded document.